# Prepared statement for Update query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

My update query is not executing. I have checked all the field headings in the dog table and they match the field headings I put in the query.

It was working fine till I added the dogImage field. However I want a user to be able to update a dog image as well. The dogImageUpload.php file runs a check on the image uploaded using a fle input type and then adds it to an uploads folder.

Please help. By the way this is my first stack overflow post so please excuse any errors or lack of ability to explain my code.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['staffID'])){
        Header("Location:../../html/vetLoginForm.html");
        die();
    }

    $id         = $_POST['id'];
    $newName    = $_POST['newName'];
    $newBreed   = $_POST['newBreed'];
    $newGender  = $_POST['newGender'];
    $newDC      = $_POST['newDC'];
    $newHeight  = $_POST['newHeight'];
    $newWeight  = $_POST['newWeight'];
    $newGenDesc = $_POST['newGenDesc'];
    $newDF      = $_POST['newDF'];
    $newStatus  = $_POST['newStatus'];

    //connect to db
    require('../../services/connection.php');

    //file that uploads image to folder in the directory
    include("dogImgUpload.php");

    //run update query
    if($updateDog = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE dog SET 
                                     name =?,
                                     breed =?,
                                     gender =?,
                                     dominantColour =?,
                                     height =?,
                                     weight =?,
                                     generalDescription =?,
                                     dateFound =?,
                                     dogImage =?,
                                     status =?,
                                     WHERE dogID =?")){
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updateDog,"ssssddssssi", $newName, $newBreed, $newGender, $newDC, $newHeight, $newWeight, $newGenDesc, $newDF, $imgFileName, $newStatus, $id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($updateDog);
        mysqli_stmt_close($updateDog);


        include("updateSuccessful.php");
        mysqli_error($con);
    }else{
        echo "Error updating record" . mysqli_error($con);
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: update your question adding the code

Comment: I have the code pasted under my question but it did not display. Why? Thanks Alex K.

Comment: the error printed is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE dogID =?' at line 12"

Comment: `status =?,` <- remove that comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updateDog,"ssssddssssi",
```

I put the datatype for the value to be inserted into the status column as a string. The status column in my database, however, carries the int datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of the set column  (remove it)

```
if($updateDog = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE dog SET 
                                 name =?,
                                 breed =?,
                                 gender =?,
                                 dominantColour =?,
                                 height =?,
                                 weight =?,
                                 generalDescription =?,
                                 dateFound =?,
                                 dogImage =?,
                                 status =?
                                 WHERE dogID =?")){
```

Comment: removed it but no difference.The error message went away though. Oh and I echoed the variable data on top, all data is coming across from the form.

Comment: You have the same error????